# Is it possible to have a WHERE only apply to 1 column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, where-clause

I have data such as:

tblBio

```
bio        bioid
some data  1
some data  2
```

tblContact

```
email        email_pub    bioid
me@me.com    1            1
you@me.com   0            2
```

I need to select

```
bio + 'email: ' + email WHERE email_pub = 1
```

I currently have:

```
SELECT b.bio + 'Email: ' + COALESCE(c.email, '')
FROM tblbio b
INNER JOIN tblContact c ON b.bioid = c.bioid
WHERE c.email_pub = 1
AND b.bioid = 1
```

However, I ALWAYS need to select bio and then append the text 'email: ' as well as the email address onto the end ONLY if email_pub is set to 1. Having the 'WHERE email_pub = 1' makes it so that if email_pub is 0 then nothing is selected.

As well, the text 'Email: ' will always show even if there is no published email.

Thank you,

Thomas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `CASE`:

```
SELECT b.bio + case when email_pub = 1 then 'Email: ' + COALESCE(c.email, '') else '' end
FROM tblbio b
INNER JOIN tblContact c ON b.bioid = c.bioid
WHERE b.bioid = 1
```

Comment: Oops. Not sure how I missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This is a scenario that calls for `CASE` - `CASE` is used for inline evaluation of expressions.

```
SELECT b.bio + 'Email: ' + CASE WHEN email_pub=1 THEN COALESCE(c.email, '') ELSE '' END
FROM tblbio b
INNER JOIN tblContact c ON b.bioid = c.bioid
WHERE b.bioid = 1
```

Comment: @bo in all fairness, I posted mine like 20 seconds after you.  It would take me a little longer to copy exactly :)

Comment: Oops. Not sure how I missed that. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah - I was just needling you cos I pipped you :) Here's a +1 - no hard feelings!